# linux bash using variables in awk command

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk

I want to count presence of 3 strings in each line of a file,
for example how many times there is "a" and the is not "b" and ...(note tha a and b are some regex codes not exactly a and b)
I have used this:

```
#! /bin/sh
array1("/(a)/" 
"/(b)/"
"/(c)/")
for i in "${array1[@]}" 
do
    for j in "${array1[@]}"
    do
        echo `/usr/bin/awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" '( i &&! j)|| ( j && i) {count++ } END { print count }' myfile.txt`
    done
done
```

but its not working with the valu of i and j (a,b,c) and it is executed as this:

```
/usr/bin/awk -v i=/(a)/ -v j=/(b)/ ( i &&! j)|| ( j && i) {count++ } END { print count } myfile.txt
```

Comment: Unclear. Read more about [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/). You could use some `$(`....`)` [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). You could start your script with `#!/bin/bash -vx` while debugging it

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eval, like this:

```
eval "awk '( "$i" &&! "$j")|| ( "$j" && "$i") {count++ } END { print count }' myfile.txt"
```

Comment: Yes you can and absolutely do NOT do that! In addition to the usual issues around use of eval (google `shell eval evil`), it makes the shell variables expand to become part of the actual awk program which ALSO can lead to even more insidious, cryptic errors.